TypeError: 'DataLoader' object is not subscriptable T5 model
I'm trying to train my model using the following commands:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, T5ForConditionalGeneration, T5Config


# IMPORT REQUIRED DATASET
path = "/content/train_set.csv"
path_val = "/content/dev_set.csv"
path_test = "/content/test_ur.csv"

ds_train = pd.read_csv(path)
ds_val = pd.read_csv(path_val)
ds_test = pd.read_csv(path_test)
ds_train


# Set the model and tokenizer
model_name = "t5-small"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name)
# Preprocess the data
inputs = []
targets = []
def preprocess_function(examples):
    inputs = examples[1]
    targets = examples[0]
    model_inputs = tokenizer(inputs, max_length=128, padding="max_length", truncation=True)
    labels = tokenizer(targets, max_length=128, padding="max_length", truncation=True)
    model_inputs["labels"] = labels["input_ids"]
    return model_inputs


ds_train = ds_train.apply(preprocess_function)#, batched=True)
ds_val = ds_val.apply(preprocess_function) #, batched=True)
#ds_test = ds_test.apply(preprocess_function)#, batched=True)

# Create a dataset for training
dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(ds_train))
dataset_val = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(ds_val))
#dataset_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(ds_test))

# Shuffle and batch the dataset
batch_size = 16
dataset_train = dataset_train.shuffle(100).batch(batch_size)
dataset_val = dataset_val.batch(batch_size)
#dataset_test = dataset_test.batch(batch_size)

from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

# Load the training and validation datasets
dataset_train = DataLoader(dataset_train, batch_size=16)
dataset_val = DataLoader(dataset_val, batch_size=16)

# Evaluate the model
def evaluate(model, dataset):
    total_loss = 0
    for batch in dataset:
        outputs = model(batch['input_ids'], attention_mask=batch['attention_mask'], labels=batch['labels'])
        loss_value = outputs.loss
        total_loss += loss_value
    return total_loss / len(dataset)

# Compile the model
model.compile()#optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4))

from transformers import TrainingArguments

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./log_results",
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,
    warmup_steps=500,
    logging_steps=100,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    eval_steps=400,
    save_steps=1e6,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=2,
    weight_decay=0.01,
)

from transformers import Trainer, default_data_collator
# Create a Trainer instance
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=dataset_train,
    eval_dataset=dataset_val,
    compute_metrics=lambda pred: {"accuracy": tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(pred.label_ids, pred.predictions), tf.float32))},
    data_collator=default_data_collator,
)

# Train the model
trainer.train()


However I get the following error:
TypeError: 'DataLoader' object is not subscriptable

.............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Does this answer your question? Problem with Dataloader object not subscriptable

@ParmanM.Alizadeh  this solution does not work for me! Any other suggestions?
I changed the code a bit!
